# Went/Got past me, got/went ahead of me

Tags: word-usage

Someone in a race passed another racer/runner.

"He got ahead of me."

"He got/went past me."

"He went ahead of me."

Do these work instead of "sped/ran past me", or simply "he passed me."

Answer (score 1):

They all work.

"He got ahead of me" suggests that you were trying to stop him from going ahead. It was difficult for him to go ahead

"He went ahead of me" or "He went past me" suggest that it was quite easy.

Comment: So are they all equally likely to be used?